# Restriccion Check en ProstgreSQL no funciona

Tags: postgresql

la restriccion check siguiente no hace su función,

```
CREATE TABLE products (

    product_no integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    price numeric
    CONSTRAINT ck_nombre CHECK (name like '[A-Z][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

Al momento de ingresar datos, unicamente me deja ingresar como texto en el campo **name** lo siguiente **'[A-Z][0-9][0-9]'**,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como hacer para que funcione??

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres permitir?  No lo dices en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente lo que intentas hacer es un CHECK contra una [expresión regular POSIX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

La sintaxis sería entonces:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    price numeric
    CONSTRAINT ck_nombre CHECK (name ~ '[A-Z][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

En donde `~` es el operador para decir que hace match y es case-sensitive.

Actualmente, al usar `LIKE`, estás definiendo el texto literalmente.

**Nota 1:** tu expresión regular dice: "Una letra mayúscula seguida de dos números", pero acepta que esa secuencia esté en cualquier parte del texto. Por lo tanto el texto: `'hola abuelita A25 te quiero mucho'` cumple con el check.

Si lo que quieres es exactamente esa secuencia, sin nada antes ni después, tu check debiera ser definido como

```
CONSTRAINT ck_nombre CHECK (name ~ '^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]$'::text)
```

O, más simple:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_nombre CHECK (name ~ '^[A-Z]\d{2}$'::text)
```

Donde los caracteres especiales `^` y `$` significan respectivamente "que empiece con..." y "que termine con...". (y `\d` significa un caracter numérico).

Comment: Gracias compañero, si funciona, además el link que me dejaste me lo aclara todo, ¡MUCHAS GRACIAS!